# Using sp_configure with CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to toggle `sp_configure`.

What I do is:

```
SELECT CAST(
        CASE
            WHEN value_in_use = 0
                THEN sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
            ELSE sp_configure 'clr enabled', 0
        END AS bit)
    FROM sys.configurations 
    WHERE name = 'clr enabled'
RECONFIGURE;
```

But it doesn't work.

How to write a toggling `sp_configure 'param'` in `T-SQL`

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3):

`CASE` is a expression used to return a value not to update something.

You need to use `IF-ELSE` like this:

```
IF @Expression THEN 
    sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
ELSE 
   sp_configure 'clr enabled', 0;
```

Comment: So how to create an expression? I did this CASE to return boolean result. Need to toggle `sp_configure` values, using `sp_configure` is required.

Comment: @Exoresion is whatever you need to be. What is the problem?

Comment: Declare a bit variable, set it and then evaluate the IF-ELSE expression as described by @JuanCarlosOropeza . Am I missing something?

Comment: `DECLARE @fun bit; SET @fun = sp_configure 'clr enabled';` won't work